# What's the relationship between checksum and full page image?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, transaction-log

Recently, I learned some about PostgreSQL data checksum and feel confused about the relationship between checksum and full page image.

As the following comment said at:

> If we need to protect hint bit updates from torn writes, WAL-log a
>   full page image of the page. This full page image is only necessary
>   if the hint bit update is the first change to the page since the
>   last checkpoint.
>
> We don't check full_page_writes here because that logic is included
>   when we call XLogInsert() since the value changes dynamically.

As I known, if we need to protect pages from torn writes including hint bit updates, we should enable `full_page_writes`. Why do I need to write full page images at the WAL if the checksum is able to detect torn pages even if `full_page_writes` is off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The checksum will produce an error if you have a torn page, but it won't correct the error. All it tells you is that it is time to restore from backup.

If you want to avoid the problem alogether, leave `full_page_writes` set to `on`.

Comment: So I think the whole work of checksum is to produce an error if I have a torn page, no matter what it is caused. Use full_page_writes to correct the error. Is it not a good idea to decouple checksum and what the full_page_writes do?

Comment: I think you understood. Checksums and `full_page_write` *are* not coupled, are they?

Comment: I just think checksum does a little bit of what `full_page_writes` should do.

Comment: Checksums tell you that something went wrong, `full_page_writes` makes sure it won't happen.